# Database of organism names (plants, animals, bugs, fish, etc.) in Chinese with literal meaning?

Tags: word, word-requests, reference-materials

I just found this [Chinese bird name website](http://sibagu.com/china/index.html), which lists the Chinese name, pinyin, and literal English "gloss" (literal English meaning), like this for the ["Ducks" section](http://sibagu.com/china/anatidae.html):

```
Dendrocygna javanica
Lesser Whistling Duck
栗树鸭
(栗樹鴨)
lì shù-yā
'chestnut tree-duck'
```

Where can I find similar resources for animal names, plant names, bug names, fish names, or more generically, organism/species names, etc. in Chinese, with the English literal meaning/gloss?

I am looking to see how Chinese literally denotes various species names but am having a hard time finding a decent and somewhat comprehensive resource like that Chinese bird name website.

Comment: try the https://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/ 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 how can I find any English related to it so I can see what it means?

Comment: https://avibase.bsc-eoc.org/checklist.jsp?region=cn&list=howardmoore

Comment: bees in Chinese culture:  https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/animals-through-chinese-history/bees-in-china/938DA35D140C2C4C8F04E108E7C2AAD8

Comment: Here is the web page that may help https://www.bing.com/search?q=chinese%20encyclopedia%20of%20animals%20and%20plants&qs=n&form=QBRE&=%25eManage%20Your%20Search%20History%25E&sp=-1&pq=chinese%20encyclopedia%20of%20animals%20and%20plants&sc=0-42&sk=&cvid=D5A23F82E9A343B7977B41A5AE1DAA6A&ghsh=0&ghacc=0&ghpl=

Answer (score 3):

If you know complex Chinese (Mandarin Chinese), you could click the links. They show Chinese bird names on the websites.

https://huijou.com/bird-english-vocabulary/

https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/WikiProject:%E9%B8%9F%E7%B1%BB

https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E9%B8%9F

https://gd-park.org.tw/en/frontpage

https://ebird.org/species/lewduc1

https://conservation.forest.gov.tw/EN